# unity game crash seems randomly when change scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

i have two scene : levelselect scene , game play scene
in game play scene , when user failure and can replay. i make a UGUI button to reload current scene.
the button code is SceneManager.LoadScene(1) , but sometime crash. not alltime ,seems when i quickly fail the game and press restart button, 3 or maybe 4 times the game crash.
it is not only in android ,in wp81 or unity editor crash too.

i am trouble a week ... thanks any help!!!!

here is the android logcat info : ( is it anyway get more error info ? thank any link,keyword and help.)

```
01-28 00:32:35.205: I/AEE/AED(24328): pid: 22948, tid: 22973, name: UnityMain 
01-28 00:32:35.205: I/AEE/AED(24328): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x80ff5fc1
01-28 00:32:35.286: I/AEE/AED(24328): r0 80ff5f51 r1 000065f0 r2 a40697a0 r3 a40697a0
01-28 00:32:35.286: I/AEE/AED(24328): r4 a3fc7f10 r5 00000003 r6 00000000 r7 3f800000
01-28 00:32:35.286: I/AEE/AED(24328): r8 845940dc r9 000003e8 sl ffffef20 fp 89839020
01-28 00:32:35.286: I/AEE/AED(24328): ip 00000000 sp 84968828 lr 83ca87a4 pc 83ca87fc cpsr 000e0010
01-28 00:32:35.286: I/AEE/AED(24328):
```

backtrace:

```
lib/arm/libunity.so (UI::CanvasRenderer::SyncDirtyElements()+132)
lib/arm/libunity.so (UI::CanvasManager::UpdateDirtyRenderers(UI::Canvas*)+196)
lib/arm/libunity.so (UI::Canvas::UpdateBatches(bool)+112)
lib/arm/libunity.so (UI::CanvasManager::WillRenderCanvases()+64)
lib/arm/libunity.so (PlayerLoop(bool, bool, IHookEvent*)+3392)
lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+704)
lib/arm/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+264)
@base.apk@classes.dex
```

Comment: well you can just put a helper bool variable like **DidStartLoadingNewLevel** to call **SceneManager.LoadScene()** only once. **SceneManager** is a new thing so I'm not surprised it has glitches like this, probably they will fix it. You should probably submit a bug though.

Comment: what is "UGUI"? if it is some third party module, ask them. You should be using the normal Unity.UI.

Comment: I think he is calling Unity UI as UGUI @JoeBlow.

Comment: see this:http://www.voidcn.com/blog/rcfalcon/article/p-6050633.html